# After typing a web address, unwanted content "salesforce.com" appears in it and redirects me

Tags: malware, virus

When I type a web address in my web browser, "force.com" or "salesforce.com" comes up in it. Here's an example: https://k12parentportal.force.com/portal_enrollmenthome>. Everything is correct except force.com being in it. I think the actual address is: https://K12parentportal/enrollmenthome>; but, it's happened so often that I can't type the real address.
 It happens in Internet Explorer and Firefox. I reset IE, but it keeps happening. This has been going on for several weeks.
 It will also redirect my browser to "salesforce.com". I had never been to your website until my browser was redirected. I ran malewarebtyes and HitmanPro Anti Malware to remove it, but it's still there. I have tried everything to remove it from my computer, but nothing works. Can you please help me with this? Thank you. Beverly `

Comment: Cross-posted to StackOverflow and Salesforce.SE.

Comment: The correct answer is likely to check with the people who gave you the original address to see what they say.  I suspect that they've set up an redirect from the local network alias to the real site on force.com, but only they can say for sure.  In any case, I don't believe this question is on topic for any of the sites you posted it to.